Are all vulnerabilities of stream cipher been found?
I recently discovered that stream ciphers specifically zip crypto is vulnerable to what i call combination attack and i am just wondering if this is new or someone discovered this already.
The equations:
$k_i = c_i \oplus p_i$
$c_i = k_i \oplus p_i$
are for encryption and decryption and then this:
$key0_i = crc32(key0_{i-1},p_i)$
$key1_i = (key1_{i-1}+ key0_i\, mod \, 256)*const + 1$
$key2_i = crc32(key2_{i-1},\frac{key1_i}{16777216})$
$x_i = key2_i |3$
$k_i = \frac{x_i*(x_i\pm 1)}{256}\, mod \, 256$
is for updating the internal state after encryption or decryption.
Notice that $key2_i$'s last 16 bits derives $k_i$.
There have been discoveries that states that given 8 consecutive plaintext bytes, One can recover 8 consecutive $k$s and eventually construct the whole internal state and an extra 5 bytes is required to filter wrong keys but they forgot one thing, substitution.
Only 8 sequence of $k$ is needed to construct internal state and 5 separate sequence of plaintext for filtering but what if we substitute the equation like this $c_i = k_i \oplus 0$, Meaning that i nullified the plaintext bytes and now $k_i = c_i$ and we can use $c_i$ to construct internal state and filter keys with 0s and later use the 1 plaintext byte (check byte) to transform the found keys into actual internal state.
So, is this new?

Not, exactly different from what is already discovered but rather an improvement.
According to previous discoveries a 12 or 13 byte sequence plaintext is required to rebuild the internal state but that is not necessarily true because $k3_i = p_i \oplus c_i$ is the same as $c_i = p_i \oplus k3_i$ meaning whatever $k3$ can do, $c_i$ can do. So previous discoveries used 8 bytes of $k3$ to build the internal state, you can also use 8 bytes $c$ to build the internal state the same way except for $key0$ which requires direct involvement of $p$.
This improvement leaves you with only 3 consecutive plaintext bytes requirement and with guaranteed internal state recovery using ciphertext.
